# Using a function to delete object properties by key name

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to figure out how I would be able to create a function that would delete an object property based on its key name

```
const objects = [
  { name: 'Luke' },
  { foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Yoda' },
  { name: 'Leia' }
]
```

Rather than just `delete.foo` is there a function I could create that would delete any property that didn't have the key 'name'?

Comment: You can code something with filter()

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Another thing to consider if you’re trying to make things homogeneous might be creating new objects instead of modifying old ones, like `objects.map(obj => ({name: obj.name}))`.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and object's [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to solve this problem.

```js
const objects = [
  { name: 'Luke' },
  { foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Yoda' },
  { name: 'Leia' }
];

const res = objects.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('name'));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter it;

```
objects.filter(object => object.name != 'Leia')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array and map only objects with `name` property.

```js
const
    objects = [{ name: 'Luke' }, { foo: 'bar' }, { name: 'Yoda' }, { name: 'Leia' }],
    result = objects
        .filter(o => 'name' in o)
        .map(({ name }) => ({ name }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object has [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method, that you can use to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the elements of your array

**Solution**

```js
objects.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('name'))
```